# Why does mysql_secure_installation fail to permit me (as MySQL root user) to enter no password?

Tags: fedora, mysql

I'm a new Fedora user.... after using Ubuntu for more than a decade, their Eric6 implementation is, per Eric6 Support, a failure.  Fedora is supposed to have it right.  So, I'm testing Fedora.

I'm running Fedora 36 and have installed MySQL per the yum instructions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-repo-excerpt/5.6/en/linux-installation-yum-repo.html).  When I get to the part of running mysql_secure_installation (step 6), the first thing it asks is for a root password... which I have not set yet.

If I press enter, it stops and complains access denied: using password no.  If I try to use my standard password (which, again, I have not set yet), it aborts with access denied:  using password yes.

So, I go through the process of stopping the server, executing mysql without networking, so I can sneak behind and set a MySQL root password using the ALter USER statement.

Having apparent success in doing this, I continue to start MySQL server again (`service mysqld start`) and receive this:

> Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start mysqld.service Job for
> mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error
> code.
>
> See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xeu
> mysqld.service" for details.

Following these directions, I get (from `systemctl status mysqld.service`)

> × mysqld.service - MySQL Server
> Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mysqld.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
> Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2022-08-29 01:26:45 CDT; 3min 3s ago
> Docs: man:mysqld(8)
> http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/en/using-systemd.html
> Process: 4521 ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/mysqld_pre_systemd (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
> Process: 4558 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/mysqld $MYSQLD_OPTS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)    Main PID: 4558 (code=exited,
> status=1/FAILURE)
> Status: "Server shutdown complete"
> Error: 13 (Permission denied)
> CPU: 3.379s
>
> Aug 29 01:26:41 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: Starting mysqld.service -

> MySQL Server... Aug 29 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE Aug
> 29 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. Aug 29 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server. Aug 29 01:26:45
> kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 3.379s CPU time.

and (from `journalctl -xeu mysqld.service`), I receive:

> Aug 29 01:08:35 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: Starting mysqld.service -
> MySQL Server... ░░ Subject: A start job for unit mysqld.service has
> begun execution ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has begun execution. ░░  ░░ The job
> identifier is 313. Aug 29 01:08:44 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE ░░
> Subject: Unit process exited ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ An
> ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited. ░░  ░░
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. Aug 29
> 01:08:44 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. ░░ Subject: Unit failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░
> Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> ░░  ░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with
> result 'exit-code'. Aug 29 01:08:44 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server. ░░ Subject: A start job
> for unit mysqld.service has failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure. ░░  ░░
> The job identifier is 313 and the job result is failed. Aug 29
> 01:08:44 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 4.192s
> CPU time. ░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime ░░
> Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░
> The unit mysqld.service completed and consumed the indicated
> resources. Aug 29 01:12:13 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: Starting
> mysqld.service - MySQL Server... ░░ Subject: A start job for unit
> mysqld.service has begun execution ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has begun execution. ░░  ░░ The job
> identifier is 3201. Aug 29 01:12:16 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE ░░
> Subject: Unit process exited ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ An
> ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited. ░░  ░░
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. Aug 29
> 01:12:16 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. ░░ Subject: Unit failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░
> Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> ░░  ░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with
> result 'exit-code'. Aug 29 01:12:16 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server. ░░ Subject: A start job
> for unit mysqld.service has failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure. ░░  ░░
> The job identifier is 3201 and the job result is failed. Aug 29
> 01:12:16 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 3.339s
> CPU time. ░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime ░░
> Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░
> The unit mysqld.service completed and consumed the indicated
> resources. Aug 29 01:20:38 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: Starting
> mysqld.service - MySQL Server... ░░ Subject: A start job for unit
> mysqld.service has begun execution ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has begun execution. ░░  ░░ The job
> identifier is 3420. Aug 29 01:20:42 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE ░░
> Subject: Unit process exited ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ An
> ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited. ░░  ░░
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. Aug 29
> 01:20:42 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. ░░ Subject: Unit failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░
> Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> ░░  ░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with
> result 'exit-code'. Aug 29 01:20:42 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server. ░░ Subject: A start job
> for unit mysqld.service has failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure. ░░  ░░
> The job identifier is 3420 and the job result is failed. Aug 29
> 01:20:42 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 3.977s
> CPU time. ░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime ░░
> Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░
> The unit mysqld.service completed and consumed the indicated
> resources. Aug 29 01:26:41 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: Starting
> mysqld.service - MySQL Server... ░░ Subject: A start job for unit
> mysqld.service has begun execution ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has begun execution. ░░  ░░ The job
> identifier is 3644. Aug 29 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> mysqld.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE ░░
> Subject: Unit process exited ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ An
> ExecStart= process belonging to unit mysqld.service has exited. ░░  ░░
> The process' exit code is 'exited' and its exit status is 1. Aug 29
> 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Failed with
> result 'exit-code'. ░░ Subject: Unit failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░
> Support: https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
> ░░  ░░ The unit mysqld.service has entered the 'failed' state with
> result 'exit-code'. Aug 29 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]:
> Failed to start mysqld.service - MySQL Server. ░░ Subject: A start job
> for unit mysqld.service has failed ░░ Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░ A
> start job for unit mysqld.service has finished with a failure. ░░  ░░
> The job identifier is 3644 and the job result is failed. Aug 29
> 01:26:45 kamz-workstation systemd[1]: mysqld.service: Consumed 3.379s
> CPU time. ░░ Subject: Resources consumed by unit runtime ░░
> Defined-By: systemd ░░ Support:
> https://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel ░░  ░░
> The unit mysqld.service completed and consumed the indicated
> resources.

I can read the reports over and over and nothing jumps out at me.  Why does mysql_secure_installation fail me?  So, I've gone from not setting a root password but mysql_secure_installation aborting because I enter no password... to setting (in behind-the-scenes manner) a root password, when I cannot get MySQL server running again.

Comment: I know this does not answer your question but is there any particular reason you are using MySQL and not MariaDB?  For most of us, they are the same thing but one comes built in and is free.  The other does not and is not.

Comment: I have explored MariaDB... and I protest that it is not 100% Drop-in replacement.  First, documentation is painful.  Second, there are no assertions that, for example, MySQLWorkbench is compatible...   With MySQL, few questions taunt me about potential incompatibility issues.

Comment: No, not 100% drop in replacement true but I have yet to not run into problems installing the real MySQL.  As far as MySQLWorkbench, I have always used it against MariaDB without a problem.  Perhaps something changed there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While installing you have to get inside as root to fix everything first. Then you can add a user and use it with that user account.

Comment: I rebuilt the machine and re-installed... my observation warns me that I had not used "sudo" when running "mysql_secure_installation."  Maybe this was the answer...

Comment: That's what I was saying. Activate root mode with sudo. If it serves your answer please select it . TIA.